# If div value equals add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

If `<div>` has a value of e.g. `Green` then add class `green`.

HTML

```
<div>Green</div>
<div>Red</div>
```

CSS

```
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

jQuery

```
if ($("div").val() == "Green") {
    $("div").addClass("green");
}
```

Class should be added to div with Green and skipped for Red.

**edit:** added extra div.

Comment: Are you loading this code after the node is created? Can you share the full HTML you're testing this one with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check `text()` of `div` for your code to work. See code below.

***Advice***: I would also encourage you to add a `class` or an `id` to your elements and target your jQuery through them to avoid any unexpected changes

Example with one div

```js
if ($("div").text() == "Green") {
  $("div").addClass("green");
}
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Green</div>
```

Example with more than one div

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Green") {
    $(this).addClass("green");
  }
});
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Green</div>
<div>Yellow</div>
<div>Green</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is my live div structure https://i.imgur.com/HJFWlO7.png Rule I use instead of just `div` is `.field-type-list-text .field-items > div`  and the class `green` is not adding to div containing `Yes`?

Comment: are you talking about adding this as CSS rule? or as a query selector?

Comment: Looks like it's not working if there's more than one div. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/qztLe2fu/1/

Comment: of course, if there are more divs, you need to iterate them, as $('div') will give you an Array

Comment: @user3108268 I have added the example

Answer (score 1):

Pure Vanilla Js if you need

```js
let element = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
let name = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML
element.classList.add(name);
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>green</div>
```

Comment: Look into queryselector() then you will automatically get the first result.

Comment: @cloned there are numerous ways to solve, I chose this which came to my mind first. thank you anyways. appreciate.